# Invalid Column Name in View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have this class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public int AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public int? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

To be inherited in all other Poco classes; such as:

```
public class District : BaseEntity
{
    public District()
    {
        Provinces = new HashSet<Province>();
    }

    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string DistrictArabicName { get; set; }
    public string DistrictEnglishName { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Province> Provinces { get; private set; }
}
```

Everything is working well. I issued:

**Enable-Migrations**

**Add-Migration Initial**

**Update-Database**

The database is created as I want.

The problem is inside the View itself. I add the datacontext as:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:DistrictVm/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The view is working as it should be. But, there is a blue line under the  telling me that there are some **Invalid Column Name** and this is happening in all of my views. It is clear in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your base class as:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
```

This means that there is no concrete implementation of any of the properties or methods in that class.

Did you mean to do this?

If this *is* the implementation of your base class then drop the `abstract`.

Comment: I removed it, but nothing happen.

Comment: Any more ideas, please.